# How to convert 'has' table in node orm

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm

I'm new to ORM, and I don't really understand the whole concept,

Now I have the following issue, suppose that I have 3 tables in mysql db,

owner: owner_id, owner_name
book: book_id, book_name
owner_has_book: owner_id (reference to owner.owner_id), book_id(reference to book.book_id)

Now, if I want to execute something like `'select * from owner, book, owner_has_book where owner.owner_id = owner_has_book.owner_id and book.book_id = owner_has_book.book_id and owner_id = 1'` How can I do this?

thx

Jasen